# Improve the Speed of Mapping A List of Lab Colors to a Second List of Lab Colors

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, lab-color-space

The problem I am having is that I have two lists that create a decently large loop that is extremely slow... 3.5 to 4 seconds slow. I'm looking to improve that. Both lists that I am using contain Lab Colors. The first list is a color palette, call it `palette_colors`.

The second list has individual lab colors that I am using to compare, call it `query_colors`.

I loop through the second `query_colors` to compare each color within the list to each one of the colors in `palette_colors` list. From that we get a distance that is used to check if the color would fall within a certain threshold.

The problem I am having is that, since `palette_colors` is a large list (about 300 items), and `query_colors` has around 100, it iterates around 30,000 times.

**So the question is, how can this be improved to run much faster?**

---

Here are some of my thoughts:

1. **Parallel Processing:** I tried to use parallel processing but either it wasn't the right context to use it in or I just didn't know what I was doing... I'm leaning towards not knowing what I was doing as the issue.
2. **Cache between processed hex values:** My first thought was to cache the distance between color combinations, however, that doesn’t help much because colors are very specific: FFFFFF != FFFFFE, even though they are visibly the same.
3. **Initial Hex Lookup Cache:** Another thought was to compare the hex values… if the hex values matched, then just return that match. However, the same problem exists that Idea 1 suffers from.
4. **Numpy Arrays + Distance Function:** Perhaps if there was a way to turn both lists into numpy arrays that only contain the Lab values, then compare each using the CIELAB2000 distance function?

Here is my fully functioning script (make sure to install colormath):

```
from time import time
from colormath.color_diff import delta_e_cie2000
from colormath.color_objects import LabColor
from operator import itemgetter

# Helper function for timing
milli_time = lambda: int(round(time() * 1000))


# when merging similar colors, check to see how much of that color there is before merging
def map_colors(query_colors, max_dist=100):

    # Contains colors from the palette that are closest to each color
    close_colors = []

    # loop through colors that we want to map
    for color_to_compare in query_colors:

        # compare lab distance with palette colors
        closest = [check_distance(palette_color, color_to_compare, max_dist) for palette_color in palette_colors]

        # Remove "none" values
        closest = [c for c in closest if c is not None]

        # sort by distance (ascending)
        closest = sorted(closest, key=itemgetter('distance'))[:1][0]['hex']

        # Remove hash
        closest = closest.replace('#','').lower()

        # Add to main list of closest colors
        close_colors.append(closest)

    return close_colors


# Checks the distance betwen lab colors
def check_distance(color_1, color_2, max_dist):
    distance = delta_e_cie2000(color_1['lab'], color_2['lab'])
    if distance < max_dist:
        return {
            'hex': color_1['hex'], 
            'lab': color_1['lab'],
            'distance': distance
        }

# list of palette colors
# Stack overflow doesn't allow this many characters, 
# so you'll have to copy and past the color palette from this url:

# https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvrwzE?editors=1010
palette_colors = [] # ^^^^

# list of colors to compare
query_colors = [{'lab': LabColor(lab_l=89.82760556495964,lab_a=-3.4924545681218055,lab_b=13.558600954011734)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=2.014962108133794,lab_a=0.22811941599047703,lab_b=1.790011046195017)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=40.39474520781096,lab_a=2.901069537563777,lab_b=11.280131535056025)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=67.39662457756837,lab_a=-2.5976442408520706,lab_b=26.652254040495404)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=32.389426017556374,lab_a=1.0164239936505115,lab_b=12.27627339551004)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=55.13922546782179,lab_a=-1.435016766528352,lab_b=35.18742442417581)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=73.96645091673257,lab_a=1.0198226618362005,lab_b=18.548230422095546)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=44.90651839131053,lab_a=-1.4672716457064805,lab_b=18.154138443480683)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=60.80488926260843,lab_a=-8.077128235007613,lab_b=16.719069040228884)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=4.179197112322317,lab_a=3.642005050652555,lab_b=3.0407269339523646)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=30.180289034511695,lab_a=1.7045267250474505,lab_b=28.01083333844222)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=44.31005006010243,lab_a=-4.362010483995816,lab_b=18.432029645523528)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=0.8423115373777676,lab_a=0.13906540788867494,lab_b=-0.3786920370309088)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=52.12865600856179,lab_a=-0.5797000071502412,lab_b=31.8790459272144)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=67.92970225276791,lab_a=-4.149165904914209,lab_b=33.253179101415256)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=60.97889320274747,lab_a=3.338501380000247,lab_b=20.062676387837676)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=2.593838857738689,lab_a=2.824229469131745,lab_b=2.704743489514988)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=7.392989008245966,lab_a=9.59267973632079,lab_b=6.729836507330539)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=98.10223593819727,lab_a=-1.3873907335449909,lab_b=4.897317053977535)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=82.313865698896,lab_a=2.588499921779952,lab_b=2.5971717623187507)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=28.371415683395696,lab_a=5.560367090545137,lab_b=0.6970013651421025)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=41.300756170362206,lab_a=-1.8010193876651093,lab_b=5.122094973647007)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=5.26507956373176,lab_a=4.548521840585698,lab_b=-0.8421897365563757)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=60.53644890578005,lab_a=1.9353937585603886,lab_b=13.731983810148996)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=18.50664175674912,lab_a=4.127558915370255,lab_b=1.5318785538835367)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=46.121107041110534,lab_a=-4.738660301778608,lab_b=11.46208844171116)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=35.096818879142134,lab_a=3.865379674380942,lab_b=8.636348905128832)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=23.053962804968776,lab_a=1.7671822304096418,lab_b=2.044120086931378)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=34.77343072376579,lab_a=-3.57662664587155,lab_b=9.259575358162131)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=35.35931031618316,lab_a=5.074166825160403,lab_b=7.782881046177659)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=21.404442965730887,lab_a=3.157463425084356,lab_b=18.391549176595827)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=86.26486893959512,lab_a=4.032848274744483,lab_b=-8.58323099615992)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=45.991759128676385,lab_a=0.491023915355826,lab_b=10.794889190806279)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=8.10395281254021,lab_a=2.434569728945693,lab_b=12.18393849532981)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=37.06003096203893,lab_a=1.8239118316595027,lab_b=25.900755157740306)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=34.339870663873945,lab_a=4.98653095415319,lab_b=1.8327067580758416)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=46.981747324933046,lab_a=5.292489697923786,lab_b=6.937195284587405)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=35.813822728158144,lab_a=29.12172183663478,lab_b=31.259045232888216)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=83.84664420563516,lab_a=4.076393227849973,lab_b=7.589758095027621)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=4.862540354567976,lab_a=3.691877768850965,lab_b=4.065132741305494)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=29.520608025204446,lab_a=15.21028328876109,lab_b=-1.9817725741452907)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=2.9184863831701477,lab_a=3.1009055082606847,lab_b=2.374657313916806)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=25.119337116801645,lab_a=6.36800573668811,lab_b=5.191791275068236)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=32.49319565030376,lab_a=4.09934993369665,lab_b=4.837690385449466)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=6.09612588470991,lab_a=9.66024466422727,lab_b=2.297265839425217)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=32.607204509025415,lab_a=37.17700423170081,lab_b=11.087136268936316)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=45.72621067797596,lab_a=4.995679962723376,lab_b=8.10305144884066)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=15.182103174406642,lab_a=17.3648698250356,lab_b=16.351707883547945)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=30.735504056893177,lab_a=20.749263489097476,lab_b=11.103091166084845)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=47.58987428222485,lab_a=21.4969535181187,lab_b=24.91820246623675)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=3.2817937526961423,lab_a=7.0384930526659755,lab_b=5.0447129238750605)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=39.176664955904386,lab_a=7.001035374555848,lab_b=7.1369181820884915)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=32.47219675839261,lab_a=-2.4501733403216597,lab_b=10.408787644368223)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=8.87372837821,lab_a=-2.5643873356231834,lab_b=5.64931313305761)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=1.742927713725976,lab_a=0.539611795069117,lab_b=-0.6652519493932862)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=33.873919675420986,lab_a=5.764566965886092,lab_b=-17.964944971494113)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=40.693479627397174,lab_a=6.595272818345682,lab_b=5.018268124660407)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=88.60103885061399,lab_a=2.6126810949935186,lab_b=-2.945792185321894)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=55.70462312256947,lab_a=6.028112199048142,lab_b=-13.056527815975972)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=9.115995988538636,lab_a=31.807462808077545,lab_b=-35.11774548995232)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=38.051505820085076,lab_a=34.8155573981796,lab_b=-18.475401488472354)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=71.92703712306943,lab_a=-3.471403558562458,lab_b=-10.445020993962896)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=26.243044230459148,lab_a=46.369628814522414,lab_b=34.6338595372704)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=66.76005751735073,lab_a=20.035224514354134,lab_b=25.87283658575612)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=63.60391924768574,lab_a=-2.891469413896064,lab_b=9.573769130513398)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=41.24069266482021,lab_a=16.278878911463096,lab_b=9.759226052984914)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=27.25079531257893,lab_a=24.94884066949429,lab_b=-48.598531002024316)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=4.265814465219158,lab_a=10.473548710425703,lab_b=4.1174226612907985)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=87.15090987843114,lab_a=7.229747311809753,lab_b=-14.635793427155486)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=54.54311545632727,lab_a=8.647572834710072,lab_b=-18.893603550071546)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=11.276968541214082,lab_a=18.169882892627108,lab_b=-30.249378295412065)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=35.090989205367,lab_a=1.0233204899371962,lab_b=-0.3006113739771554)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=2.9317972315881953,lab_a=0.8523516700251477,lab_b=0.29972821911726233)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=42.71927233847029,lab_a=15.072870104265279,lab_b=-31.54622665459128)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=1.622807369995023,lab_a=1.0292382494377224,lab_b=1.2173768955478448)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=85.05833643040985,lab_a=1.955449992315006,lab_b=-9.91904370358645)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=1.6648316964409666,lab_a=0.13905563573127222,lab_b=-0.37887416481000025)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=53.47424677173646,lab_a=1.322931077791023,lab_b=-0.14670143432404803)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=3.7059376097529935,lab_a=0.31588132922930057,lab_b=0.11051016676932868)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=1.4885457056861533,lab_a=0.6786902325009586,lab_b=-1.043701149385401)}, {'lab': LabColor(lab_l=16.298330353761287,lab_a=0.4909724855400033,lab_b=3.125329071162186)}]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_time = milli_time()

    colors = map_colors(query_colors)

    print(colors)
    print('Script took', milli_time() - start_time, 'milliseconds to run.')
```

Comment: How did you try parallelising exactly? With mult-threading or multi-processing? What are you actually trying to achieve - the nearest colour in the palette for each input colour or a sorted list of N nearest colours?

Comment: I tried multi-processing but not multi-threading but I'm not familiar with either. I tried it on the inner loop where I pre-generated a list of tuples as inputs that were passed into the `check_distance` function. I really only need the single closest color for each input color and not the entire sorted list.

Comment: It seems odd to maintain and then sort a list of hundreds of things you don't want! Why not check each colour against the nearest so far as you calculate them and only save it if nearer than previous closest. Then you can save memory and sorting time. Also, it should be easily parallelisable by splitting your list of colours to match into say 4 and running each quarter in parallel.

Comment: I think that whether or not I keep the color is actually irrelevant to the speed because you still have to look at all the colors. How else would you know which color is nearest to the input color without comparing them all? There are millions and millions of colors options that could be used as inputs. Would you care to put your code suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of color object and list comprehension you can use the array function from `color_diff_matrix` on raw Lab values:

```
from colormath.color_diff_matrix import delta_e_cie2000

# Colors as raw Lab values
# Some test data
palette_colors = np.tile([ 2.01496211,  0.22811942,  1.79001105], [300, 1])
color_to_compare = np.array([ 89.82760556,  -3.49245457,  13.55860095])

dist = delta_e_cie2000(color_to_compare, palette_colors)
closest = palette_colors[np.argmin(dist)]  # also color as raw Lab components
```

This should already give a nice speedup, but I got another factor 5 by jitting the function with numba:

```
from colormath.color_diff_matrix import delta_e_cie2000
from numba import jit

delta_e_cie2000_jit = jit(delta_e_cie2000)
dist = delta_e_cie2000_jit(color_to_compare, palette_colors)
... # the rest is the same
```

Note that the first execution of the jitted function is slow due to the compilation process.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the [nearest neighbor problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).  The usual approach for an *exact* answer with many query points is based on space partitioning.  This would be easy for the CIE76 metric because it is Euclidean (in *L*a*b** space): a *k-d* tree can be used directly.

It’s still possible to apply the space-partitioning approach with the newer, more complicated metrics.  However, for an exact result you have to derive a bound on the distance between a point and whatever partitions you choose: that is, the *minimum* distance between a point and *any* point that would be on the other side.  A coordinate-aligned plane (as used for the Euclidean case) makes for the simplest partitioning, but might make a poor bound.

If an *approximate* answer suffices, you can approximate the 2000 metric with the 76 one for the purposes of partitioning.  You can also switch to a binning approach, where you round the coordinates onto a coarse grid and then search it in a structured fashion to find the closest match.  Each of these approaches often provides but cannot guarantee an exact result.